# Query for documents where field is largest

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have data such this

```
{
"UID": "a24asdb34-asd42ljdf-ikloewqr",
"createdById" : 1,
"name" : "name1",
"createDate" : 01.14.2019,
"latest" : 369
},
{
"UID": "a24asdb34-asd42ljdf-ikloewqr",
"createdById" : 1,
"name" : "name2",
"createDate" : 01.14.2019
"latest": 395
},
{
"UID": "a24asdb34-asd42ljdf-ikloewqr",
"createdById" : 1,
"name" : "name3",
"createDate" : 01.14.2019,
"latest" : 450
```

}

i need query which select the one element of document where field **latest** is greatest than such field in another document elements

Java code

```
@Query(value ="[ {$sort : {latest: -1}},{$limit : 1} ]",fields = "{ 'UID' : 1, 'name' : 1, createDate : 1}")
    Page<MyObject> findByCreatedById(String userId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: you mean like selecting the max: db.collection.find().sort({latest:-1}).limit(1) ?

Comment: Which is nothing AT ALL to do with the JPA API. It isn't even anything to do with "Spring Data JPA". It could be "Spring Data MongoDB" which is a totally different API, but then you ought to know what API you are using ...

Comment: @BillyFrost do you know how to implement it to Spring Data JPA as @Query?

Comment: Don't you read? You are NOT USING THE JPA API or the SPRING DATA JPA API (which is for RDBMS datastores ... and you're not using RDBMS). You are presumably using the "Spring Data MongoDB" API. But you present none of your actual Java code

Comment: @BillyFrost added Java code

Comment: Yes, you're not using Spring Data JPA, as I said some time ago. You've fixed the tags now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.orders.find(
                     [
                      { $sort: { latest: -1 } },
                       { $limit: 1 }
                     ]
                   )
```

Sort in descending order of the latest field and limit the result size to 1.

Comment: why the limit is 2?